# Deserializar en Java

Tags: java, serialización

En mi programa tengo un objeto `Maestro`, `Alumno` y un objeto `Materia`, el cuál contiene un `ArrayList` de maestros y alumnos.

¿Cómo puedo serializar un ArrayList de materias?

Ya lo intenté de la misma forma que logré serializar un ArrayList de números enteros, el problema viene cuando es un ArrayList de un objeto que a su vez tiene objetos adentro y lanza un `InvalidClassException`.

> Objeto alumno

```
package intendo2;

import java.io.Serializable;
public class Alumno extends Persona implements Serializable  {
    int edad;
    int calificacion;

    public Alumno(int id, String nombre, String apellidoPaterno, String apellidoMaterno, String correo, int edad, int calificacion){
        super(id, nombre, apellidoPaterno, apellidoMaterno, correo);
        this.edad = edad;
        this.calificacion = calificacion;
    }

    public Alumno(){
        super(69420, "Andres", "Abimeri", "Romero", "andres.abimeri@gmail.com" );
        this.edad = 20;
        this.calificacion = 69;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Alumno{" + "edad=" + edad + ", calificacion=" + calificacion + '}';
    }


}
```

> Objeto Maestro

```
package intendo2;

import java.io.Serializable;


public class Profesor extends Persona implements Serializable{
    String titulo;




    public Profesor (int id, String nombre, String apellidoPaterno, String apellidoMaterno, String correo, String titulo){
        super(id, nombre, apellidoPaterno, apellidoMaterno, correo);
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }


    public Profesor(){
        super(69420, "Andres", "Abimeri", "Romero", "andres.abimeri@gmail.com" );
        this.titulo = "Ing. en Informática";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Profesor{" + "titulo=" + titulo + '}';
    }


}
```

> Objeto materia

```
package intendo2;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Materia implements Serializable {
    int id;
    String nombre;

    ArrayList<Alumno>  alumnos = new ArrayList<Alumno>();
    ArrayList<Profesor>  profesores = new ArrayList<Profesor>();


    public Materia(int id, String nombre){
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public Materia(){
        this.id = 55555;
        this.nombre = "Materia Generica";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Materia{" + "id=" + id + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", alumnos=" + alumnos + ", profesores=" + profesores + '}';
    }


}
```

En mi main tengo:

```
static ArrayList<Materia> materias = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: puedes mostrarnos código?

Comment: Ya agregué lo necesario creo

Comment: si es posible, trata de poner el código directamente, es más fácil pode replicar tu error si podemos copiar y pegar tu código, que tratar de escribirlo todo en imágenes :)

Comment: ¿por qué pones esto: `dsfasdfasdfadfasdfadsfasdfasdfadfasdfadsfasdfasdfadfasdfadsfasdfasdfadfasdfadsfasdfasdfadfasdfadsfasdfasdfadfasdf`? parece spam

Comment: Ya lo agregué, perdón, soy medio nuevo aqui. Agregue todo ese texto abajo porque me decía que mi publicación era mayormente código

Comment: no por favor quítala eso solo genera ruido y no es necesario

Comment: Listo, ya elimine eso